# How to disable okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log from printing on my console while executing the watson assistant's functionalities using java?

Tags: java, ibm-watson, okhttp, watson-conversation

I want only the output not that logs printing on my console.

[image: I want only the output not that logs printing on my console]

Comment: please check out the image

Comment: did you find the solution?