# How to disable okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log for PubNub using log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, okhttp, pubnub

As the title mentions, how do we disable `okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log` for any third party dependency in this case might be PubNub. Currently our log files are getting filled up with following text

```
30-Aug-2019 20:40:54.791 INFO [OkHttp http://ps.pndsn.com/...] okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2019 20:40:54 GMT
30-Aug-2019 20:40:54.791 INFO [OkHttp http://ps.pndsn.com/...] okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log Content-Type: text/javascript; charset="UTF-8"
30-Aug-2019 20:40:54.791 INFO [OkHttp http://ps.pndsn.com/...] okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log Content-Length: 30
30-Aug-2019 20:40:54.791 INFO [OkHttp http://ps.pndsn.com/...] okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log Connection: keep-alive
30-Aug-2019 20:40:54.791 INFO [OkHttp http://ps.pndsn.com/...] okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log Cache-Control: no-cache
30-Aug-2019 20:40:54.791 INFO [OkHttp http://ps.pndsn.com/...] okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
30-Aug-2019 20:40:54.791 INFO [OkHttp http://ps.pndsn.com/...] okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.log Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
```

This question [has already being asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51894551) but with no answers.

We did try some Hail Mary approach like populating our `log4j.properties` file with following entries

```
log4j.logger.com.squareup.okhttp3=OFF
log4j.logger.okhttp3.internal.platform=OFF
```

but they do not seem to work.

Most of these logs are coming for PubNub and that has a dependency for package

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

hence we suspect that could be the package causing these problems.

Any one with any insights on how to suppress these excess logs?

Comment: Soham, do you happen to have logging enabled? Check for setLogVerbosity property during PubNub initialization. What do you have it set to?

Comment: @ParasWadehra you are correct we have set log verbosity to `BODY`, which was causing all the trouble. Thank you. We set the property value `setLogVerbosity` to `PNLogVerbosity.NONE` to resolve our issue. Thank you.

Comment: OK, let me reply that as the answer so you can mark that as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Soham,

It seems like you have logging enabled.

Please update

```
pnConfiguration.setLogVerbosity(PNLogVerbosity.BODY);
```

to

```
pnConfiguration.setLogVerbosity(PNLogVerbosity.NONE);
```

and that should solve the issue.